# Pandas: mapping data series (float to string) WITHOUT removal of trailing zeros

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I am trying to create a data series containing strings of the form:

`"%.2f +/- %.2f"`

using two pandas data series (the measurements and their error). Here is how I've implemented this:

```
df["F"] = df["Fint"].map(str) + " +/- " + df["Fint Err"].map(str)
```

However, the map(str) removes trailing zeros from the values in the series.

E.g for source 'VLA 3 at 6lambda'.

```
In[101]: df["Fint"]
Out[101]: 
Source  Lambda    Fint
VLA 2   6.0       0.15
        3.6       0.19
VLA 3   6.0       0.40
        3.6       0.29
```

```
In[102]: df["Fint"].map(str)
Out[102]: 
Source  Lambda
VLA 2   6.0       0.15
        3.6       0.19
VLA 3   6.0        0.4
```

How do I stop the trailing zeros from being removed?

Obviously as you can see I'm actually working with a data frame (but as map is a data series func I thought this would simplify the question), if there's a way of achieving this with applymap instead I'd be happy to know.

Thanks!

Comment: May I ask what web service you used to generate this run-code-snippet part of the question? It looks very cool...

Comment: It looks cool and is very useless. Editing it away. @Greg Don't abuse the snippet for things other than live HTML/js

Comment: I suggest writing your own lambda expression to do string formatting, and specify the digits preserved after decimal point.

Comment: @sehe I can think of some use cases of it that are more meaningful. You can't say this service is useless for all humanity, right?

Comment: I didn't. What makes you think I was referring to anything outside this question. Next time, just view the source: http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/33046966/1

Comment: regarding the snippet thing, sorry its my first time asking a question ^^ but  thanks for your suggestion Mai. I'm going to try out @Field Cady's answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the data starts off as floats then it doesn't have "trailing zeros".  But from your example it sounds like what you really want is to have all the numbers be at least 4 digits long, adding trailing zeros if need be.  Try this:

```
# function that maps float->str, then pads with "0" up to length 4
to_4digit_str = lambda flt: str(flt).ljust(4,"0")


df["F"] = df["Fint"].map(str) + " +/- " + df["Fint Err"].map(to_4digit_str)
```

Comment: Awesome thanks, that's worked like a charm (with map(to_4d...) on both series). I tried something like that but couldn't get it to work. Is there any way to use map with a format string something like this:

fmt = "lambda x: %.2f" % str(x) for i, x in df["Fint"]"

Comment: minus the lambda expression

Comment: Not sure I completely understand your question.  You can do something like
    fmt = "%i %s"
    format_line = lambda r: fmt % (r['Fint'], str(r['Fint err']).ljust(4,'0'))
    df['formatted_col'] = df.apply(format_line, axis=1)
The two tricks I'm using here are 1) using %i in the format string to signify that it's an integer (%f means a float, but it renders w/o trailing zeros) and 2) the apply function on df.  Make sure that axis=1 with that one.